# How do I import BERTforsequencclassification in same way importing bert?

Tags: import, bert-language-model

I have a full code work on bert model using this code segment

```
import bert #BertForSequenceClassification
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization
```

How I can import BertForSequenceClassification instead of bert and work on the same code, given that I am working using transformers?
thanks

Comment: If you are using huggingface transformers library, then you can use it as follows:
`from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification`

Comment: yes, but an error appears in usnig run_clasifier, optimization and tokenization because they are not compatible with BertForSequenceClassification

Comment: Which `run_classifier.py` are you using?

Comment: from BERT's TF Hub loadable module

Comment: `BertForSequenceClassification` is a class available in `transformers` library of hugging-face. It is not available in the BERT provided by the authors of BERT.

Comment: good answer thank you vert much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using huggingface `transformers` library, then you can use it as follows:

`from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification`

`BertForSequenceClassification` is a class available in transformers library of hugging-face. It is not available in the BERT provided by the authors of BERT